# Getting loading time of css source (url)

Tags: php

I want to get loading time in ms, of one url. It would be either css, js or img url. Like this for example - `http://images.apple.com/global/nav/styles/navigation.css`.

I think i need to use curl for this, this is my current method:

```
$url1 = 'http://images.apple.com/global/nav/styles/navigation.css';
$curl1 = curl_init();       
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_URL, $url1); 
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
curl_exec($curl1); 
$contime1 = curl_getinfo($curl1, CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME);
```

The value i get from this method is too big (im comparing it with value from pingdom). Can someone suggest me proper curl functions to use for this, or another way of calculating this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `microtime()` function

[microtime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) Manual

**For Ex.**

```
<?php
    $time = microtime(true);
    file('http://images.apple.com/global/nav/styles/navigation.css');
    echo "Time : ".(microtime(true) - $time)." Seconds";
?>
```

**Output**

```
Time : 0.31984090805054 Seconds
```

Comment: I remember someone recommended me not to use micro time for this, but ill try and see the results

Comment: microtime() is a quicker way

Answer (score 0):

```
$time = microtime(true); // Gets microseconds
file('http://images.apple.com/global/nav/styles/navigation.css');
echo "Time Elapsed: ".(microtime(true) - $time)."s";
```

Answer (score 0):

**use microtime & file get contents**

```
<?php

$url = 'http://images.apple.com/global/nav/styles/navigation.css';
$total_time = get_load_time($url) . '';
echo 'Data retrieved in ' . $total_time . ' seconds.';

function get_load_time($url) {
  $time1 = explode(' ', microtime());
  $start = $time1[1] + $time1[0];
  @file_get_contents($url);
  $time2 = explode(' ', microtime());
  $finish = $time2[1] + $time2[0];
  return round(($finish - $start), 4);
}

?>
```

// Sample Output

```
Data retrieved in 1.7756 seconds.
```